# Clases y objetos en java

Tags: java

Entre sus explicaciones y más videos y más ejemplos que vi logré hacer este código, lo ejecuté y todo va bien pero siendo sincera más de la mitad de lo que hice no entiendo, ni el porqué, pero me guíe del ejemplo y funciona hasta ahora;

Más específicamente no entiendo qué vendría siendo la parte donde coloque `public void`, y allí en cada uno realice los distintos cálculos que necesitaba y después hice `public double` para lo que yo supongo devolver el valor del resultado de la operación que hice.

El `public void` que nombré como `comparaciondepanaderias` al final de esa parte que contiene las 3 variables en las cuales se guardo el resultado de los procesos realmente no sé qué es ni por qué debía hacerse, pero seguí el ejemplo al igual que después lo volví a utilizar, y dentro de sus llaves coloqué todo lo que se mostraría en pantalla sobre los resultados y al final coloqué un `sc.close` que tampoco sé bien porque fue tal vez solo es para dar por terminado la lectura de datos en el programa, pero no estoy segura de nada.

En la parte del condicional `if` para acceder a los valores que quería comparar escribí `panaderia1.get` seguido del nombre de la variable, pero no estaba segura si era `get` o `set` o simplemente el nombre de la variable, solo justo como había hecho en el código anterior.

Realmente traté de entender el porqué de cada cosa que hacía pero hay unas que simplemente no les encontré sentido, sin embargo, como los ejemplos daban buenos resultados, hice lo mismo que vi en ellos. Si tuvieran el tiempo de revisar mi nuevo código y poder aclarar algunas de mis dudas se los agradecería enormemente.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
class Panaderia{
    int piezaspan;
    double preciopieza = 0.5;
    double pagototaldoñita;
    
    double tasadolar;
    double preciodolarporkg=2.15;
    double pesodelpan=0.09;
    double pagototalfina;
    double pagofinaenbs;
    public void setpagototaldoñita() {
    pagototaldoñita = piezaspan * preciopieza;
    }

    public void setpagototalfina() {
    pagototalfina = (piezaspan * 0.09) * preciodolarporkg;
 pagototalfina = Math.round(pagototalfina*100)/100d;
    }
    
    public void setpagofinaenbs(){
    pagofinaenbs = pagototalfina*tasadolar;
 pagofinaenbs = Math.round(pagofinaenbs*100)/100d;
    }
    
    public double getpagototaldoñita() {
    return pagototaldoñita;
  }
    
    public double getpagototalfina(){
    return pagototalfina;
    }  
    
    public double getpagofinaenbs(){
    return pagofinaenbs;    
        
   }
   
   public void comparaciondepanaderias() {
    setpagototaldoñita();
    setpagototalfina();
    setpagofinaenbs();
  }
  
    
}
public class Main
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Panaderia panaderia1 = new Panaderia();//llamando al objeto de tipo panaderia 
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.println("En la panaderia 'La doñita' se vende el pan por pieza con un costo de 0,5bs c/u");
     System.out.println("mientras que en la panaderia 'La fina' se vende el pan en $/kg con un costo de 2.15$/kg\n");
   
     System.out.println("Este programa lo ayudara a comparar los precios entre panaderias");
     System.out.println("teniendo en cuenta que cada pan pesa 0.09 kg (90gr) aprox. en ambos sitios\n");
     
     
  System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de piezas de pan que desea comprar");
  panaderia1.piezaspan = sc.nextInt();
  
  System.out.println("Ingrese a que tasa (bs) reciben el dolar en 'La fina'");
  panaderia1.tasadolar = sc.nextDouble();
  
  panaderia1.comparaciondepanaderias();
  
  System.out.println("\n\nEl total de bs a pagar en la panaderia 'La doñita' es de "+panaderia1.getpagototaldoñita()+"bs");
  System.out.println("mientras que el total a pagar por la misma cantidad de panes en 'La fina' es de "+ panaderia1.getpagototalfina()+"$, que equivalen a "+panaderia1.getpagofinaenbs()+"bs\n");
  System.out.println("Si comparamos ambos precios en bs segun la tasa indicada podemos ver que");
  
  if(panaderia1.getpagofinaenbs()>panaderia1.getpagototaldoñita()) {
     System.out.println("la panaderia que vende por pieza (La doñita) tiene menor precio que la que vende en $/kg (La fina)");
  }
  if(panaderia1.getpagofinaenbs()<panaderia1.getpagototaldoñita()){
  System.out.println("la panaderia que vende en $/kg (La fina) tiene menor precio que la que vende por pieza (La doñita)");    
  }
  if(panaderia1.getpagofinaenbs()==panaderia1.getpagototaldoñita()){
  System.out.println("Los precios en ambas panaderias son iguales");    
  }
  
  
  sc.close();
  
 }
}
```

Comment: Vi tu pregunta ayer, y ahora veo que te lanzaste a modelar un objeto `Panaderia`, aunque le faltan muchas mejoras, ya es un avance. Pero claro, sin entender los conceptos fundamentales entiendo que estés perdida (ya ha sido valiente de tu parte lanzarte a diseñar un objeto). `public void` significa que el método es *publico*  y que no devuelve nada (`void` = vacío). `public double` singifica que el método es público y que devuelve un objeto del tipo `double`  y `sc.close()` es para cerrar el `Scanner` que abriste al principio para recoger los datos que el usuario escriba en pantalla ...

Comment: Pasando ahora a tu clase ... es todavía imperfecta. Si no recuerdo mal, en la pregunta de ayer te hablaban de **dos panaderías**, y que una vendería en dólares y otra en bolívares. Entonces, tíenes que diseñar tu clase `Panaderia` de forma que refleje eso y luego crear **dos instancias** de `Panaderia`, una en dólares y otra en bolívares y hacer las comparaciones **desde fuera** de la clase `Panaderia`, invocando un método que te devuelva el total vendido de cada una. Otra cosa, en Java hay algo que se llama *convención de nombre*. Lo digo porque tus nombres de método son penosos ...

Comment: ¿qué es `doñita`?  ¿? Hay más nombres y propiedades que, al leerlos, no se entiende lo que significan. Considera renombrar cada cosa, de forma que se pueda entender y podamos ayudarte mejor. Como quiera, con respecto a tu anterior pregunta, el código está bien encaminado, ya tienes tu `Panaderia`, ahora hay que mejorar un poco el código. Si no entiendes algo, pregunta.

Comment: En tu ejercicio estas nombrando 3 panaderías ,cualquiera pensaría que debieron ser 3 objetos de la `clase Panadería` cada una debió tener un atributo nombre y un método para calcular su precio respectivo y luego comparar esos precios con el método comparar de la `clase Panadería`, como lo planteas mas parece un ejercicio de *programación estructurada* a uno de *POO*

Comment: tenes un buen tutorial en este link asi podras entender que es un constructor de una clase y como se generan instancias de una clase podras asi tambien inicializarla https://www.it.uc3m.es/java/git-gisc/units/oo-herencia/slides/ProgramacionOrientadaAObjetos.pdf

Comment: tambien tenes este otro tutorial hace los ejemplos son simples https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/index.php?inicio=20